# How NOT to play sounds when phone is muted?

Tags: android, kotlin, audio

I am making an app using a `MediaPlayer` object to play a sound every time a function gets called. However, this sound is playing even though the phone is muted. How can I avoid this?

This is basically the code I have

```
private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bruh)
        ...
}

private fun getRandomAnswer(){
        ...
        mediaPlayer.start()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method check if phone is in silent mode by AudioManager code and you can set volume to 0 if it's in vibrate or silent mode,

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
  case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
    //Silent mode set media volume to 0 if playing
    mediaPlayer setVolume(0,0);
    break;
  case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
    //vibrate mode set media volume to 0 if playing
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0);
    break;
  case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
    //normal mode
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(1,1);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. What if I want to add background music, where should I check that?

Comment: If I have answered this question then please accept and upvote it. You can add another question for this because it will help others. Thank you :)

Comment: Where do you want to give background music? for what?

Comment: I want to put background music in my app, if the phone turns silent, then set volume down, if it's the opposite, set volume up

Comment: I have written the logic of setting volume inside case statement. You need to write broadcast receiver for getting the Audiomanager state at runtime and there you can set the volume. I hope it will help you.